# Can't use fs in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, fs

I was codding a simple bot for discord, and I noticed that when i use fs, the app doesn't deploy. I need to access a file that is inside a folder. But when I use:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

The app doesn't deploy, I tried to do everything in one .js file, but i really need to use modules.export
I cant even use:

```
const configFile = require('./config')
```

Comment: Which error did you get on Heroku Logs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "the app doesn't deploy" mean? What's the specific error message with full traceback? Please read [ask].

Comment: Bassicaly, I use heroku to host a discord bot, when I use fs, the bot doesn't go online, and when I don't use, it goes online

Answer (score 0):

If whatever look here with same case as me:
console error looking as bad directory on heroku, my manually app working.
Local node.js need using / or 
On Heroku you must use /
So I change this line:

```
const folderPath = __dirname + "\\my_modules";
```

to this:

```
const folderPath = __dirname + "\\my_modules";
```

I used type module so `__dirname` is my variable setup by package URL and path.